# Remove scroll bars from Web Browser control

Tags: vb6

How can I remove the scrollbars from a web browser control using VB6?

Answer (score 6):

Handle the [WebBrowser.DocumentComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768282(v=vs.85).aspx) event:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, ByVal URL As Object)
        WebBrowser1.Document.body.Scroll = "no"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
WebBrowser1.Document.body.setattribute "scroll", "no"
```

[Source](http://www.vbcity.com/forums/topic.asp?tid=22779)

Answer (score 0):

in the page that you need to load add this to body tag:
`<body scroll='no'>`